# Associative mapped cache, word addressable

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I have an associative mapped cache with 10 tag bits and an offset of 7bits.

What is the size of each main memory block in words(word addressable) and main memory size in words?

i worked it out as:
block size would 2^7bits. 
main memory would be 2^17bits.

the issue I am facing is, how do I get them to be word addressable with this much information given. I have managed to get the above result in byte-addressable. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. `associative mapped cache` - set size? *block size would $2^7$ **bits*** ↔ *managed to get the above result in **byte**-addressable* hm, hm, hm, hm.

Comment: Could you assist me with the above problem I am facing? @greybeard

Comment: I can try and hint again that you seem to be given *tag* and *offset* size in *bits*, and asked about number or *words* (addressable unit, to judge from `word addressable`). Try to clean up `worked it out as:` and think about whether `in byte-addressable` fits in anywhere. I can't work out main memory size from the above: I'd need the sizes of the *index* (*number of cache sets*, which I tried to make you consider asking for the *set size*) and the *address space* (I'm *almost* ready to *assume* address size given by $tag\ size + index\ size + offset\ size$).